# 2D Array of numbers not working correctly with ngx-openlayers

Tags: javascript, angular, openlayers

I have an Angular2 web app which uses ngx-openlayers to apply geometry lines onto the map.

I also have a 2D array of lat/lon pairs, such as: `[[lon, lat],[lon,lat]]`

However, this array isn't working when applying it using the ngx-openlayers syntax:

```
 <aol-geometry-linestring>
            <aol-collection-coordinates [coordinates]="dijkstraRoute" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'">
            </aol-collection-coordinates>
 </aol-geometry-linestring>
```

It creates the geometry line, but places it near South Africa! (It should be in the UK)

However, when I apply the array coords manually it works fine e.g.:

```
<aol-collection-coordinates [coordinates]="[[-1.1379196, 52.632556],[-1.137877,52.63257]]" [srid]="'EPSG:4326'">
```

I'm not sure if the array isn't the right format... but it's just a 2D array of numbers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you running in to troubles because of the minus before your lon! How is your array looking like?
Some relevant code is missing...

Comment: I resolved the issue. For some reason it was outputting the 2D number array with values enclosed in quotes. After parsing them as numbers it fixed the line geometry positioning